# Capacitor capacitor.config.json chances doesnt work

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to chance my App from cordova to capacitor. So i have less experiment with capacitor.
First i want to chance the hostname, but it doesnt work.
I write my new hostname in the capacitor.config.json and run my project (ionic build ,npx cap copy). But nothing happens. I remove the IOS file and create a new one with npx cap ios.
i think the config doesnt refresh.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `servers`, to `server`, it should work then